# My first independent C++ program. How can i improve it?

Tags: c++, calculator

Just a simple calculator I wrote as my first piece of coding in C++, I am happy to receive constructive criticism on how to improve!
I only used operations with whole numbers in hopes of just simplifying it for now!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Simple calculator that handles +,-,*,/ with whole numbers


int Add (int x, int y){  
return (x+y);
}
int Sub (int x, int y){
return (x-y);
}
int Mult (int x, int y){
return (x*y);
}
int Div (int x, int y){
return (x/y);
}
int main(){
enum operation {sum, subtract, multiply, divide};
operation operationSelect;
int sel;
int a,b,c;

cout << "Which 2 numbers do you want to perform an operation on?\n";
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cout << "Which operation do you want to perform? sum, subtract, multiply, divide (0-3)\n";
cin >> sel;
operationSelect = operation(sel);


if (operationSelect == sum){
    c = Add (a, b);
    cout << "The result is: " << c << endl;
}

if (operationSelect == subtract){
    c = Sub (a, b);
    cout << "The result is: " << c << endl;
}

if (operationSelect == multiply){
    c = Mult (a, b);
    cout << "The result is: " << c << endl;
}

if (operationSelect == divide){
    c = Div (a, b);
    cout << "The result is: " << c << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Improve it by indenting the code.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place to post this

Comment: Not used to stackoverflows formatting, sorry about poor indentation!

Comment: This question is off-topic on stack overflow it'd be better placed on the [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) . That said, you should think about what you want to improve, just consider possible improvements and whether or not they're necessary or useful. I.e. run-time optimisation would be completely pointless, but you may consider ways check for and fix bugs, a bug to fix atm is that it's possible for a user to perform integer division by 0. You could also add features, the current input is a bit cumbersome, you could try your hand at writing a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of thoughts from my side:

- as already pointed out proper indentation is important
- imo function/method names should be verbs and therefore I would not capitalize it ie. Add -> add.
- it is only possible to select exactly 1 operation, so an if-elseif-else block would make more sense, or even better a switch statement.
- you should extract the line for presenting the result to the user out of the if-statements and write it only once before the return statement. Copying the same code multiple times should be avoided when possible.